# Installing mysql using chef-solo

Tags: mysql, chef-solo

I have a VM to train myself with chef solo.
Installed it and configured a kitchen. Configured my own VM as the only node in the kitchen.
Used Librarian to download the mysql cookbook and updated the runlist.

What is the command to use - to install the mysql on my node?

Thanks,
Liora

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following command :

```
chef-solo -j JSON_ATTRIBS -c CONFIG
```

here

- JSON_ATTRIB is the json data for the VM configuration
- CONFIG is the configuration file which contains the runlist to be run on the VM

More help can be found using `chef-solo --help`